# I am not sure why the code will not output any statements. When I run it in my IDE nothing is outputted

Tags: java

```
package Fall21;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BalloonRideWeight {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int personWeight = sc.nextInt();
        int totalWeight = 0;
        
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
            totalWeight +=personWeight;
            personWeight =sc.nextInt();
        }
        
        if (totalWeight >500) 
            System.out.println("Everyone too fat.");
            
        else 
            System.out.println("Just right.");
        
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

would this be a runtime issue ???
I am just learning basics so any answers with arrays and more complex levels of code are not needed.

Comment: Are you inputting some integers on the command line? The command blocks on `int n = sc.nextInt();` until you enter some stuff.

Answer (score 2):

It probably doesn't output anything because u are using `Scanner` which expects input. When I run your program and I enter the following input

```
1
1
1
```

I get as output

```
Just right.
```

Each of these invocations

```
sc.nextInt();
```

expects you to enter an input that gets stored in the declared variable (left hand side of the statement).

So with my first two inputs, the values
`n = 1, personWeight = 1`
then the loop iterates 1 time, which contains another scanner invocation setting the `personWeight`. Which I again set to `1`.

Only then it reaches the if condition that prints something to the console. See this for more info: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_user_input.asp

EDIT:

If you want to parse multiple ints from one line, u can do:

```
String[] arguments = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
int[] ints = new int[arguments.length];
for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
   ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(arguments[i]);
}
```

Or a fancier version:

```
int[] ints = Arrays
   .stream(scanner.nextLine().split(""))
   .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
   .toArray();
```

Comment: Okay that makes more sense. I guess I didn't hit enter after each number when entered. The reason why I asked was because I was trying to run it with an input: "4 81 700 125 55" and nothing would pop up. I guess what I'm asking is what if I want the scanner to read multiple integers of input at once and output the final result. I want it to read each int value at the same time, espcially after each iteration of the for loop.

Comment: @PokyesKromtit you should ask yourself whether you want to use program arguments (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) or a scanner. I edited my answer with an approach to parse multiple ints from one line.

Comment: Okay thank you!! I appreciate the edits and will work on my code accordingly